# Cosa vuol dire "troncare il nodo"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *Nichel* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Molti impiegati avevano un loro orto, attorno alla palazzina quadrata degli uffici; alcuni avevano anche un pollaio. Era successo varie volte che le galline dell’uno sconfinassero nell’orto dell’altro, danneggiandolo, e ne erano nate noiose controversie e faide, che male si confacevano alla serenità del luogo ed all’indole sbrigativa del Direttore. Questi **aveva troncato il nodo** da par suo: aveva fatto comprare un fucile Flobert, e lo aveva appeso a un chiodo nel suo ufficio. Chiunque vedesse dalla finestra una gallina straniera razzolare nel proprio orto aveva il diritto di prendere il fucile e di spararle due volte: ma occorreva la flagranza.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "troncare il nodo" che appare in questo passaggio. Ho cercato alla voce "nodo" di alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovata. Una ricerca su Google di "troncare il nodo", però, dà parecchie occorrenze. Quindi, si tratta di una locuzione più o meno comune?

Tra le diverse accezioni di "nodo" che appaiono sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nodo/) non riesco a vedere a quale corrisponda, anche si immagino che possa essere qualcosa del punto 4, che riporta parecchi usi figurati. Il rapporto con queste persone? Il bisogno di sfogo di queste persone? Gli ostacoli che impedivano che regnasse la serenità in quel posto?

Comment: Sembra un riferimento a https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodo_gordiano, che anche quella pagina Treccani cita con un rimando.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Dubito che il Treccani rimandi alla Wikipedia... (lo so che non intendevi questo :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il riferimento è al *[nodo di Gordio](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodo_gordiano)*, impossibile o, almeno, molto difficile da sciogliere. Problema che Alessandro Magno risolse in modo molto pragmatico, con un colpo di spada.

Quindi il “nodo” in questione è il problema delle galline, la cui “soluzione” è un po' brutale.

Si veda http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gordiano per avere conferma (grazie della segnalazione nei commenti).

> *tagliare, troncare, recidere il nodo gordiano*, superare una situazione difficile andando direttamente allo scopo senza perdere tempo a voler eliminare ogni singolo ostacolo.