# Significato di "da par suo" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Cerio* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto questo passaggio che fa riferimento al laboratorio del Lager (grassetto mio):

> Sotto l’aspetto, appunto, delle sostanze che si potessero rubare con profitto, quel laboratorio era terreno vergine, tutto da esplorare. C’erano benzina ed alcool, prede banali e scomode: molti li rubavano, in vari punti del cantiere, l’offerta era alta ed alto anche il rischio, perché per i liquidi ci vogliono recipienti. È il grande problema dell’imballaggio, che ogni chimico esperto conosce: e lo conosceva bene il Padre Eterno, che lo ha risolto brillantemente, **da par suo**, con le membrane cellulari, il guscio delle uova, la buccia multipla degli aranci, e la nostra pelle, perché liquidi infine siamo anche noi.

Non capisco il significato della locuzione "da par suo" in questo passaggio.

Questa stessa espressione appare anche nel passo citato in [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13020/), anche lì in riferimento a risolvere  un problema ("troncare il nodo").

Quando lessi quel altro racconto, con aiuto di questa definizione del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pari1)

> **c.** Riferito a persone, che hanno la medesima condizione sociale, lo stesso grado, talora anche le stesse qualità; con questo sign., è per lo più sostantivato e si usa in determinate locuz.: *trattare qualcuno da p.*, o *da p. a p.*; *non si sente inferiore a nessuno e tratta tutti da pari*. Frequente soprattutto in unione con agg. possessivi: *usa questo tono quando sei con i tuoi p.!*; *se ne stia con i p. suoi*; *sopra gli omeri de’ suoi p., con funeral pompa di cera e di canti, alla chiesa ... n’era portato* (Boccaccio); *tu, che modello D’ogni nobil virtù, d’ogn’atto eccelso Esser dei fra’ tuoi p., i p. tuoi A conoscere apprendi* (Parini); *se l’arroganza de’ vostri p. fosse legge per i p. miei* (Manzoni). Al sing., dicendo *un par mio*, *un par tuo*, *un par suo*, e sim. (dov’è usata solitamente la forma tronca *par*), si intende riferirsi alla persona stessa, senza confronto con altre ma in rapporto alla sua condizione, alle sue qualità: *da un par suo c’è da aspettarsi di tutto* (cioè, da uno come lui, da lui in quanto è ciò che è); *non è da par tuo agire così*; *vive, si mantiene da par suo*; *non sono accuse da fare a un galantuomo par mio!* In qualche caso indica non il grado sociale ma le doti e capacità intellettuali: *questa sì che è una risposta da par tuo*; *ha scritto un articolo da par suo*, quale ci si doveva aspettare conoscendo il suo valore

interpretai che il senso dell'espressione era che il Direttore aveva risolto il  problema come l'avrebbe fatto un suo uguale, cioè, una persona qualsiasi con la sua stessa "indole sbrigativa". Tuttavia, non mi sembra che questo significato abbia senso nel contesto del brano citato in questa domanda, che si riferisce a Dio. Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

Comment: È abbastanza calzante la parafrasi “quale ci si doveva aspettare conoscendo il suo valore”. È una forma di spirito: chi saprebbe risolvere un certo problema meglio di Dio (se esiste)?

Comment: @DaG:   Quindi, si tratterebe di un modo scherzoso di esprimere che il problema è stato risolto nel modo più brillante possibile, quale si potrebbe aspettare appunto da Dio?  (Lo stesso Levi aveva detto: «Devo dire che l’esperienza di Auschwitz è stata tale per me da spazzare qualsiasi resto di educazione religiosa che pure ho avuto… C’è Auschwitz, quindi non può esserci Dio. Non trovo una soluzione al dilemma. La cerco, ma non la trovo». Ma non credo che questo abbia importanza per interpretare il testo.)

Comment: @dag il commento di DaG è corretto. Annoto solo che "da par suo" può essere usato anche in modo dispregiativo. Cioé, alla fine non aggiunge nulla, è solo un giro di parole per dire "come ci si aspettava".

Comment: Aaah! Grazie, @egreg: corretto!

Comment: @Charo :-D :-D ;-)

Answer (score 1):

La locuzione "Da par suo" possiamo interpretarla in diversi modi:

possiamo interpretarla come "Da parte sua",
come indicato nel [seguente articolo](https://italianosemplicemente.com/2019/02/25/da-par-suo/#:%7E:text=Cio%C3%A8%20da%20uno%20come%20lui,%E2%80%9Cda%20uno%20come%20lui%E2%80%9D.)

> Da un par suo c’era da aspettarselo
>
> In questa frase non si fa riferimento ad “un suo pari“, ma
> semplicemente a lui: da un par suo diventa “da parte sua”. Ad ogni
> modo è importante dire che “par” nella frase “da par suo” significa
> pari, e non “parte”. Questo però come abbiamo visto non ci impedisce
> di costruire una frase molto simile utilizzando la parola “parte”.

In pratica possiamo dire che:
il Padre Eterno, ha risolto il problema  brillantemente,
*da parte sua*, (oppure liberamente,
*per quanto gli riguarda*, oppure
*dal suo canto*)
con le membrane cellulari...

oppure, possiamo interpretarla nel seguente modo, tratto da [dizionari.repubblica.it](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/P/pari.html)

> || Da par suo, in maniera adeguata alla sua condizione sociale, al suo livello intellettuale, alla sua fama ecc.

il Padre Eterno, ha risolto il problema brillantemente, *in maniera conforme alle sue capacità*, con le membrane cellulari ...

Insomma, se l'autore voleva dire che il Padre Eterno aveva risolto il problema dell'imballaggio *in contrapposizione agli altri chimici*, possiamo propendere per la prima interpretazione, cioè, *da parte sua, per quanto gli riguardava,* lo ha risolto in un certo modo;

se invece l'autore voleva sottolineare che lo aveva risolto *brillantemente*,  *come solo lui da fare*, *come è suo solito*, possiamo propendere per la seconda interpretazione.

Comment: Per curiosità, chi è l'autore del primo articolo che citi? È affidabile?

Comment: @DaG, l'articolo è raggiungibile all'indirizzo https://italianosemplicemente.com/2019/02/25/da-par-suo/#:%7E:text=Cio%C3%A8%20da%20uno%20come%20lui,%E2%80%9Cda%20uno%20come%20lui%E2%80%9D.;
non è specificata la fonte della frase citata;
non so quanto sia affidabile, ma risponde pienamente a cosa evoca nella mia mente la locuzione "da par suo"

Comment: Grazie, avevo visto il link, ma non sono riuscito a trovare chi abbia scritto quell'articolo.

Comment: E poi... si tratta veramente di due significati diversi di questa espressione? Questo non lo capisco del tutto bene. Vuol dire che l'interpretazione del significato nell'altro racconto potrebbe essere diversa da quella ho fatto io?   Cioè, potrebbe significare che il Direttore  aveva risolto il problema lui solo, senza l'aiuto di nessuno e non che l'aveva risolto come si aspetterebbe di qualcuno con la sua stessa "indole sbrigativa"?

Comment: per @Charo, l'esempio citato nell'altra domanda, quello del Direttore dall'indole sbtigativa, mi sembra sicuramente adeguata la seconda interpretazione, cioè che aveva risolto alla sua maniera, come gli si addice, perché 1) non c'è contrapposizione con nessuno, 2) ha menzionato l'indole 3) è a fine frase

Se inceve il racconto dicesse, "alcuni direttori hanno adottato delle soluzioni soft, mentre il direttore A, "da par suo", ha adottato la soluzione del fucile" a me dà molto il senso che ha agito "da parte sua", cioè ha preferito andare per la sua strada e ha preso la sua decisione.

Comment: Dubito fortemente che “par” possa significare “parte”. Se anche fosse un troncamento di “parte” (che non già di per sé è impossibile), il possessivo sarebbe concordato e “parte” è indiscutibilmente femminile.

Comment: @egreg: E questo potrebbe significare che interpretare "da par suo" come una locuzione col significato di "da parte sua", come proposto su quel sito web, sia qualche sorta di "misconception"? Veramente questa accezione non sono riuscita a trovarla su nessun dizionario. Adesso l'ho trovato anche sul [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000610.jpg), che di solito è abbastanza completo.

Comment: @Charo Per avallare la prima interpretazione, "da parte sua", posso far notare che Google Translator traduce "da par suo" in inglese come "for his part" e word reference (https://www.wordreference.com/iten/da%20par%20suo) traduce "for his part, on his part"; appena posso magari, cerco di editare la mia risposta per spiegare meglio la mia interpretazione.